# Local field 'created_at' in class 'Attachment' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Timestampable'

Tags: django, database-migration

I have the following two models:

```
class Timestampable(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not self.created_at:
            self.created_at = now
        self.updated_at = now

        super(Timestampable, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Attachment(Timestampable, models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mime = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publicly_accessible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I try to migrate these models, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'created_at' in class 'Attachment' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Timestampable'
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290750/fielderror-local-field-password-in-class-user-clashes-with-field-of-similar), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662686/local-field-clashes-with-field-of-similar-name), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468136/django-custom-user-field-clashes-with-abstractbaseuser) that this should work when the base class is abstract. However, I marked it as abstract it still it doesn't seem to work. What else could be wrong? I am using Django 1.8.14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I used to have the class `Timestampable` not inherit from `models.Model`. Therefore, in one of my initial migrations, I had the line:

```
bases=(at_common.behaviours.Timestampable, models.Model),
```

I was looking for a way to remove this. Turned out that I just had to delete this line from the initial migration file.

Answer (score 2):

Because your Timestampable model already extends from models.Model. You don't need extend Attachment model.

please use:

```
class Attachment(Timestampable):
```

instead of:

```
class Attachment(Timestampable, models.Model):
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I noticed that too after I had posted it. It didn't solve the problem though.